# what does "toffset" and "ooffset" stand for in the java String method: regionMatches(int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)?

Tags: java, string

the java method regionMatches has these parameters: (int toffset, String other, int ooffset, int len)

What does "t" and "o" that is prepended to the word "offset" stand for? Here is the link to the documentation of the method, regionMatches.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-int-java.lang.String-int-int-

Comment: "this" and "other", I guess?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc

**Parameters**

- toffset - the starting offset of the subregion in **this** string
- **other** - **the string argument**
- ooffset - the starting offset of the subregion in **the string argument** (the "other" parameter)